# Position absolute image only shows half during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a component that is supposed to slide up and down depending on some user action. The component must hold an image in the top which is positioned absolute, on a wrapper which is positioned fixed.

Everything is fine and dandy, however during the slide up and down effect, for which I am using jQuery, only the bottom half of the image is shown.
When the animation is over, the image is shown as it's supposed to do.

I have some CSS which looks like:

```
.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.picture {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

I've made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7sg3x6zn/

Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you need to override the overflow: hidden that is set on the callback of both slideDown() and slideUp().

You can do that without changing your stylesheet, if you alter your code like that:

```
$(function() {

    $('#show').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').slideDown().css('overflow','visible');
  });

  $('#hide').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').slideUp().css('overflow','visible');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
overflow: initial !important;
```

to wrapper class like the example
https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/ug7szyzv/

this is happening because the jquery function adds overflow:hidden during the animation..

Answer (score 0):

The animation slideDown, and slideUp uses `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper element doing the animation.

And because of the negative top position of the images is outside the wrapper. So to avoid the image being cut in half delete the line: `top: -40px`

Hope this make sense :)